# RewriteRule prevents encoding

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, encoding

In my htaccess, I have rewrite rule for my search page to create clean URL;

Original URL :

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?keyword=apple
```

RewriteRule :

```
RewriteRule ^keyword/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?keyword=$1
```

Clean URL :

```
http://www.example.com/keyword/apple
```

That works perfectly unless I type foreign characters. For example, If I write

```
http://www.example.com/keyword/değişmek
```

I get 404. That makes sense because the letter ğ and ş are foreign letters. They have to be encoded. But if I write that keyword in original URL,

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?keyword=değişmek
```

It works. I get results. Also, I tried to encode what users type in input search for clean URL

```
var url = encodeURIComponent($("#search-input").val());
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/keyword/"+ url ; 
console.log(url);
```

didn't work. I get 404. I checked the console.log and the user input is encoded. Therefore, I think rewriterule causes encoding problem. So I have tried to add some flags related to encoding.

```
RewriteRule ^keyword/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?keyword=$1 [NE]
RewriteRule ^keyword/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?keyword=$1 [B]
RewriteRule ^keyword/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?keyword=$1 [NE,B]
```

didn't work. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you defined only **`alphanumeric characters`** using `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)`,

Try using `([^/]+)` instead If you want to allow everything

or use `([\p{L}0-9]+)` to allow only unicode letters and numbers,

But it will not allow special marks like `%&*()#!@`